# How to make the div takes the full height of the page when the browser height shrink in CSS

Tags: html, css

When we set a block level element height to 100% it will take the full height `min-height: 100%;` of the page or at least the full height of its parent, however what is strange for me as I'm currently learning CSS is that when I **shrink the height of the browser window**

Here is a few seconds video to show what I mean. [Video](https://streamable.com/z0cs1p)

As you can already see from the video, when I make the height of the browser very short and then scroll down I see that the *content section* no longer takes the full height until I make the browser height a little bit longer, however *the sidebar and the profile sections* don't do that since their width are a less than the *content section*.

**So the question is: How to make the div to keep its full height when the browser height shrinks and then scroll down as you can see from the video?**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 90%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  left: calc(15% + 2em);
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.profile {
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(75% + 4em);
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: black;
  min-height: 100%;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h2>Content</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
<div class="profile">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
```

My code on codepen: [Code](https://codepen.io/rashiddev/pen/VwzgYaQ)

Comment: use `flexbox` + `flex-grow`. `height: 100%` means 100% of the parents height. It requires a defined height while the default is calculated to fit-content. Alternativly use `min-height: 100vh` to set the height to 100% of the viewport

Answer (score 0):

**CSS-Grid solution**

One easy way is to use CSS-Grid. I cut your code down to the part that is actually "usefull" and removed all unecessary or non-working code.

`display: grid` activates CSS-Grid
`grid-template-columns: 15% auto 15%` creates your 3 column layout while `auto` occupies the remaining space.
`min-height: 100vh` sizes the boxes to be at least as heigh as the viewport.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% auto 15%;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}





/* original CSS cut down */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar,
.content,
.profile {
  padding: 2em;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.profile {
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h2>Content</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
<div class="profile">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Flexbox solution:**

To use Flexbox you have to use `display: flex`. Same as the `CSS-Grid` solution you also give the body a `min-height: 100vh` to fill up at least the entire viewport.
To get your intended 3 column layout, you have to define your left and right side as `width: 15%`.
To have the middle column fill up the remaining space, you just need to add: `flex-grow: 1;`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar,
.profile {
  width: 15%;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}



/* original CSS cut down */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar,
.content,
.profile {
  padding: 2em;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.profile {
  background-color: firebrick;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <h2>Content</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
<div class="profile">
  <h2>Profile</h2>
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, voluptatibus tenetur. Et facere provident voluptatem praesentium illum explicabo vel architecto eum repellat facilis. Eum repudiandae nobis ad aliquid aut. Ut.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however its not what I'm looking since the 3 divs now don't occupy the whole page's height. And is the css-grid system the only solution here? @tacoshy

Comment: What do you mean? I gave you 2 possible solutions and in both snippets the divs always occupy at least the entire screens height.

Comment: I really appreciate your solutions, however I need you to go and watch the video again. What I mean by that is to try make the browser page height less than 20% and then scroll down then your gonna see that the divs no longer occupy the full height. @tacoshy